# Laravel 6 email confirmation on registration is skipped

Tags: laravel, email, email-verification

I am trying to install the Laravel functionality - send email for confirmation on registration.
The issue is that after registration form, I am automatically logged in - I am not getting to the page - "check your email for confirmation".

So I am following the docs at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/verification for Laravel 6
I also looked online for some more detailed instructions and found this:
https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-6-email-verification-tutorialexample.html

I installed the sendemail as instructed here
https://tecadmin.net/install-sendmail-on-ubuntu/
I am not sure that is working - but to get Laravel show me the page with the  "check your email for confirmation" - I dont think I need this?

Is there a step I am missing and is not described in the docs?

Comment: Check your logs to see if there (and what) are problems with sending mails from your application. Also check your .env file to see what mail driver you are using (should be `mail` in your case)

Comment: Thanks will do - but how does the actual sending of email affect the Laravel to display or not the "check your email for confirmation" page? login? Are the two connected?

Comment: Check out your User model. It's using `MustVerifyEmail` contract, that has a method called `sendEmailVerificationNotification` to handle that for you. Take a look at `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail`

Comment: ah ok so I added the use MustVerifyEmail but i dindnt implement it in the class... sorry. Closing this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the docs are not very clear - here is what needs to be done

**After register - redirect** to a page where we tell users they have to check the email and confirm

in `Auth/RegisterController` add this function

```
protected function redirectTo() {
    return route('verificationSent');
}
```

in web.php add the new route

```
Route::get('/verification-sent', 'IndexController@verificationSent')->name('verificationSent');
```

in `IndexController` add the function that handles the new page

```
public function verificationSent() {
    return view('auth.verify');
}
```

If you want - you can add same functionality for a landing page for when the user clicked on the link in email and confirmed the registration - just add the redirectTo function in VerificationController this time, then the new route etc.

**How to disable user logging in on register**

add this function to RegisterController

```
/**
 * Overwrite the function from the RegisterUser trait
 * 
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    //DISABLE LOGIN
    //$this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```